# RSpec でエラーになるはずのテストが通ってしまう

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

現在ruby on railsにてテストコードを書いております。
エラーでは無いのですが、以下の現象が発生しました。
RSpecwo使ったuserモデルのテストコードです。(devise利用)

以下が問題のテストコードです。
25行目でnicknameを空にしているので通常であればエラーとなるのですが、テストコードを正常に通過してしまいます。

**期待すること**
通常であればエラーが発生し、そのエラー分をexpectで記述したいのですが、そもそもエラーが発生せず困っている。

```ruby
require 'rails_helper'
describe User do
  before do
    @user = FactoryBot.build(:user)
  end

  describe 'ユーザー新規登録' do
    context '新規登録がうまくいくとき' do
      it "nicknameとemail、passwordとpassword_confirmationが存在すれば登録できる" do
        expect(@user).to be_valid
      end
      it "nicknameが8文字以下で登録できる" do
        @user.nickname = "aaaaaaaa"
        expect(@user).to be_valid
      end
      it "passwordが6文字以上であれば登録できる" do
        @user.password = "000000"
        @user.password_confirmation = "000000"
        expect(@user).to be_valid
      end
    end

    context '新規登録がうまくいかないとき' do
      it "nicknameが空だと登録できない" do
        @user.nickname = ''
        @user.valid?
        binding.pry
      end
      it "nicknameが9文字以上であれば登録できない" do
        @user.nickname = 'aaaaabccccccccccccccccbbb'
        @user.valid?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

以下のように10行目でnicknameカラムにpresence: trueのバリデーションをかけているのですが、テストが正常に通過してしまいます。

```ruby
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :nutritions
  has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :fav_nutritions, through: :favorites, source: :nutrition

  validates :nickname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 8 }

  def already_favorited?(nutrition, current_user)
    Favorite.exists?(user_id: current_user.id, nutrition_id: nutrition.id)
  end
end
```

`bundle exec rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb` コマンドでテストしますがなぜか成功してしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

通常であればnicknameが空の時はエラーになると思うのですが何故なのでしょうか？
ローカル上でのブラウザでは正常にバリデーションがかかっております。（nisknameを空で登録しようとするとエラー文が返る）

ご教示頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: '新規登録がうまくいかないとき'の方にはexpect()がないため、RSpecでエラーが捕捉されていないように見えます。例えば、`@user.valid?`を`except(@user).not_to be_valid`としたらどうなるでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。そちらの方法で解決することが出来ました。